# Designing Token Based Authorization Server Request/Response

Tags: security, design-patterns, spring-security, access-token, http-token-authentication

Identity in our services are based on a token stored in a database. This is acquired by the client by logging in with a username and password.

Each time a resource is requested, we plan to validate the token and determine if the user is authorized to access that resource.

Our services are deployed separately, and the authorization server can be reached via HTTP.

What's the best practice/common way in authorizing the requests?

**Sending token with requested permission and role**

I was thinking of passing in the token with the role and requested permission of the user in the token validation request to the authorization server.

```
{
 token: 'xyz',
 role: 'ROLE_ADMIN',
 permission: 'SAVE_USER'
}
```

and respond with: 200 for success, 401 for an invalid token, 403 if they are not authorized to use the permission.

**Sending only the token in authorization request**

Another approach in mind is sending just the token in the token in the token validation request to the authorization server.

```
{
 token: 'xyz'
}
```

and respond with all the permissions and roles the user have:

```
{
 roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'],
 permissions: ['SAVE_USER', 'DELETE_USER', 'SHOW_USER']
}
```

Which of these are more advisable?
Or are there any other/patterns approaches I can consider?

Comment: I think its better to use Spring OAuth, if you are using Spring MVC. It already handling token based authentication by sending you just a random uuid(as token) while actual information will be stored in database. So whenever you are trying to access a resource using that token, spring will check roles/permission against that token and will validate the user accordingly

Comment: @Afridi I'm not currently using OAuth though. Is it advisable to use Spring OAuth for non OAuth authentication/authorization?

Answer (score 0):

As you're talking about a "service", it means that most likely your service prefers to know what can it do before it requests for it.

For example you may want to highlight those buttons user can click before a request arrives.

So I think the second approach would be fine. And a kind of first approach is gonna be executed while a request is passed to the server, eg. user wants to remove something and it doesn't have sufficient access, so gets a 403.

Talking about security, in both ways you described, there are sufficient checks, eg. in the first one, when user asks for some action, it GETS CHECKED before getting executed and that's what should be done.

Comment: Just to confirm, is this a normal way to authorize request on services?

Comment: @froi which one do you mean? sending token with every request? I believe yes, it is. Many famous services use it.